# Solr - how to return a specific field that contains characters like '#' or '-'

Tags: solr

If I have a field in Solr with a hash in e.g. report1#name_s how can I return all results for that field.

When I try '...&fl=report1%23name_s' I get the error 'undefined field: "report1"'

I have tried putting the field name within quotations but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field names should consist of alphanumeric or underscore characters only and not start with a digit. When selection a field name - java variable naming convention is recommend.

for more refer

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+Fields